# JSON string from client to Struts 2 Action. How to handle just using struts.xml configuration

Tags: struts2, client-side

I ve a question. I have a JSON string ready to send to an Struts2 action from a ajax javascript function. Action is called properly, but i dont know how to get the JSON parameter from its method.

Is any struts.xml action configuration that makes me able to put automatically the information in the object, just as ..attributeClass?

In a similar way that i send from the server to the jqGrid (a javascript object to make grids with data inside, just with struts configuration result type=json and the attributes of the object that i want to send as a JSON string to the client web)?

Or maybe the only way is forget the struts.xml configuration and "hard programming" HttpServletRequest parameter, that has JSON string?

Thank you!

Comment: No need for `hard core programming`. use any of the plugin mentioned in the below post and you are ready to go.Let framework handle the thing in clean way for you

Answer (score 1):

Both the [JSON plugin](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/WW/JSON%20Plugin) and [REST plugin](http://struts.apache.org/2.x/docs/rest-plugin.html) can do what you want. Which makes more sense to use depends on the application.

You *could* do the work manually, either by accessing the request directly (not recommended), or by manually parsing a string parameter.